# How to selectively perform multiple updates (not add or update) in a transaction?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have this method:

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateIfExist<T>(string cacheKey, IDictionary<string, T> dictionary)
    {
        ITransaction tran = m_connection.GetDatabase().CreateTransaction();

        List<HashEntry> hashEntries = new List<HashEntry>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, T> keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(cacheKey, keyValuePair.Key)); // <-- this guy is the problem

            HashEntry hashEntry = GetHashEntry(keyValuePair);
            hashEntries.Add(hashEntry);
        }

        bool committed = await tran.ExecuteAsync();
        if (committed)
        {
            await tran.HashSetAsync(cacheKey, hashEntries.ToArray()));
        }

        return committed;
    }
```

My intention is to perform *a pure update*, that is, update those keys in `dictionary` which are also present in cached hash. I don't want new key value pairs from `dictionary` to be inserted to the cached hash. But the above performs an "all or nothing" update, that is, if any one of the keys from dictionary is missing in the cached hash then nothing is updated.

---

E.g. Say I have this hash in my Redis cache:

```
myKey foo bar
      goo baz
```

And say, this is my input dictionary:

```
foo newBar
qoo qux
```

After I call my method..

***Expected in cache:***

```
myKey foo newBar // updated since the field exists in hash
      goo baz
```

***Actual:***

```
myKey foo bar   // no change to cache
      goo baz
```

---

**Note:** If Lua script is the only way I will try that, but primarily looking for a native SE.Redis API approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native redis way to do this directly, hence there is no native SE-Redis way to do this directly. What we'd really want here is an `XX` modifier (see `SET` for what I mean), but that doesn't exist on any hash command - only `NX`, which is the opposite of what you want (`NX` is "when not exists").

You *could* do this without Lua by:

- checking the existence of each first
- pruning your update set
- creating a transaction of just the pruned updates, with conditions to assert the checks
- etc

But that is a *lot* of round trips and operations, and there is a high chance of failure due to conflicting data changes. As such, I would say that the best way to do this would be to use Lua (as is often the case for multiple related operations that you want to be atomic). I would send one value in `KEYS`, and a pair of values per entry in `ARGV`, and loop in the Lua, essentially (completely untested - might not even be valid syntax)

```lua
for i=1, #ARGV, 2 do
    if redis.call('hexists', KEYS[1], ARGV[i]) == 1then
        redis.call('hset', KEYS[1], ARGV[i], ARGV[i+1])
    end
end
```

Comment: When trying to do the same thing for a single key value pair (not a collection), I just learned that `await GetDatabase().HashSetAsync(cacheKey, kvp.Key, SerializeToJson(kvp.Value), When.Exists);` doesn't work either. It throws a *"Exists is not valid in this context; the permitted values are: Always, NotExists"*. Interesting. I wonder why so many of these common operations are missing from Redis :(

Comment: @nawfal you could propose it over on the redis GitHub. The logical command would be `HSETXX`